# How do I get my Apple Wireless Keyboard and Magic Mouse to work on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: wireless, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, apple

I know I have already asked one Ubuntu question but that's just cause I've been having to borrow someone else's usb keyboard and mouse all this time...

I have tried to set it up in the Bluetooth settings but they are never detected at the same time and when it does detect it the device gets lost again... Unlike some people here my apple wireless keyboard and Magic Mouse don't work at all.

What am I not doing? How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it possible or impossible?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you only need to pair it using bluetooth settings in Ubuntu and then press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> twice in order to toggle <kbd>numlock</kbd>, as described in [Ubuntu's community help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard). That's a typical issue when using Apple keyboard.

Take a look at the mentioned wiki page, as it describes how to properly configure this keyboard.